# Setting the environment in Laravel 5

Tags: php, environment-variables, laravel-5

I'm trying to change the environment in my app from local to production. I've modified the .env file but whenever I run a query it's not using the config I have in config/database.php, or the database settings in .env, but the default homestead @ localhost. How can I change the environment to production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment all I needed to do was restart the server, in my case `artisan serve`. It only loads the environment when starting, so any changes don't take effect whilst it's running.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following line into your boostrap/app.php

```
  $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.local.env');
```

you can change the file name here ('.local.env') what environment file need to run

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5 the .env file is the file you need to edit. The DB values are stored there.

This file should be in .gitignore as there is a .env.example

change the

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_KEY=yourkey

DB_HOST=tost
DB_DATABASE=db
DB_USERNAME=un
DB_PASSWORD=pwd

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

to look like that on your production environment as it no longer uses the values in config/database

files in that config dir should keep config that is the same across environments

Comment: OK, I've done that yet it's not using the details in that file. It's still trying to use homestead @ localhost to connect to the database.

Comment: If you run `php artisan env` in your project directory, what does it print out ?

Comment: Artisan detects the environment file fine, and I'm able to use migrate to create tables. However when I try to create an account using the default page I get the error that the system couldn't connect to the database using  "homestead @ localhost".

Comment: Hmm, that's a little strange. In your config directory, in the databases file, are there any values set there to do with homestead ? perhaps could you do a recursive grep for 'homestead' in your project directory ?

Comment: I've searched for homestead in all the files using Komodo. The only place it found it was in the error logs and the .env.example file. The database config file never had any reference to homestead. It has forge as the username and database in everything, except for the mysql one where I've entered my database details.

Comment: OK, turns out that all I needed to do was after changing the .env file I had to restart `artisan serve`... I hadn't tried running it since the problem occurred and it just came to me that it might have been cached until the server restarted.

Comment: Awesome. Glad you came right! Thanks for posting your find/fix too :)